# Deep Copy of a circular linked list

Tags: c#, circular-list

Can anyone share their views on how can we do a deep copy a circular linked list in C# (possible explanation of code)?

Basically what I was looking is how do we deep copy the circular single linked list which has a loop and then making a deep copy of it...

We have few algorithms which can identify a loop in a linked list and then figuring out the head of the list. But after that how do we seperate the copy from the whole list..

Comment: Basically what i was looking is how do we deep copy the circular single linked list which has a loop and then making a deep copy of it...We have few algorithms which can identify a loop in a linked list and then figuring out the head of the list. But after that how do we seperate the copy from the whole list..

Comment: You can use the edit button if you want to add or modify informations.
Anyhow, this library was created to copy objects:
http://automapper.codeplex.com/. It's inspired by a java's library called Dozer

Answer (score 0):

Why not just keep a reference to the first element you start at, and use that as your head for your copy, and keep moving to `'Next()` until you come across that same first element?

Once you do link the last element of your new linked list to the first?

Obviously for each element you do some sort of `DeepClone()` that is implemented by that class.